# PHPExcel 1.7.9 updating from 1.7.6 errors

Tags: phpexcel

I've used PHPExcel 1.7.6 to generate Excel Files. I recently updated to v1.7.9 but this gives me an error when trying to setCellValue on the active sheet of the phpExcel object.

The error is:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPExcel_Worksheet::updateCacheData() in
>   C:\wamp\www\platform\class\PHPExcel_v1.7.9\PHPExcel\Cell.php on line
>   106

The Phpexcel object is created by loading an existing xlsx file.

I was not getting this error before the update. Do you know if there are any known bugs in 1.7.9 that could produce the error?

Comment: It sounds as though you may be working with a mix of 1.7.6 and 1.7.9 files: did you install the version 1.7.9 over the top of the existing 1.7.6, or as a clean install?

Comment: OK thanks Mark Baker, I'll look into it and post when I'm done!

Comment: I dont see any problem with 1.7.9 I think you have missed out some file